# Nestjs Event Sourcing - Event Persistence

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, nestjs, cqrs, event-sourcing

How is event persistence handled in Nestjs? It's not clear in the documentation (Read the [CQRS Recipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs)), how we should persist events and how we reply them using snapshots. Its also not clear how to create the read side separated from the write side.

Comment: Read side of events?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The documentation states *"To facilitate [the CQRS] model, Nest provides a **lightweight** CQRS module."*, and that is exactly what it offers. Unlike the rest of NestJS the small cqrs object model is not all that opinionated, leaving a lot of architectural decisions for the implementer.

So the object model allows a clean way to create `Command`, `Saga`, `Query` and `Event` objects and provide handlers for them, define `AggregateRoot` entities and having messagebuses for publishing, but not much more. Leaving you with the basics for doing domain-driven design.

How you integrate them is entirely up to you. If you do a [Github search](https://github.com/search?q=nestjs+cqrs) on 'nest + cqrs' you'll find many different approaches. Some choices being e.g.:

- Create commands directly in controllers vs. in application-layer services.
- Commands return no data vs. return errors-only vs. return write-side-only data.
- Aggregate root and DB/ORM entity are the same class (not DDD best-practice).
- Events emitted manually via eventbus vs. on aggregate root via mergeObjectContext.
- Single database for read- and write-side models vs. multiple db's.

Your question about persisting events refers to the last point, and hints to implementing Event Sourcing (ES) on top of CQRS. Note that doing so is entirely optional. While ES comes with a lot of interesting features, you should only apply this pattern if your application requirements warrant it. ES comes with additional complexity, that should not be underestimated. So reading up on the pros and cons is definitely advised (the [cqrs.nu](https://cqrs.nu) FAQ is a good starter). Note that you can just implement CQRS and add ES later, when the need arises.

So Event sourcing (and event persistence) are not part of the NestJS CQRS module. When you decide to persist your events you can use a specialized database such as [Eventstore](https://eventstore.org/) or you can implement it in your relational db (see for Postgres e.g. [Event Storage in Postgres](https://dev.to/kspeakman/event-storage-in-postgres-4dk2), [PostgreSQL Event Sourcing](https://github.com/tobyhede/postgresql-event-sourcing/) or full-blown project [message-db](https://github.com/message-db/message-db)).

With Event Sourcing your setup may look like what's described in the good article [Event-Sourcing with NestJS](https://thehardcoded.blog/event-sourcing-with-nestjs) by Eliran Natan:

[image: NestJS Event Sourced CQRS Architecture Concept]

In this setup you have to make *projections* to load a - usually - relational DB with denormalized views for the read-side of your architecture. Without ES this may not be needed, and you can use your ORM or direct SQL queries to hydrate your `Query` objects with appropriate data.

So that's about it. One last tip is to never make direct calls to your read-side logic from write-side code (a recipe for trouble as it destroys the command/query separation).

Comment: "One last tip is to never make direct calls to your read-side logic from write-side code (a recipe for trouble as it destroys the command/query separation)."

Is this true only for a read and write side within the same aggregate? Is it okay to call a read side of one aggregate from the write side of another?

Comment: @G.Kashtanov I believe that is context/domain specific. If the saga does not mutate the data you are trying to read, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I've read about event sourcing and I've found that we can roll back the system state to a specific place. e.g roll back a transaction and give money back using payment microservice when our wallet microservice get fails. Is it correct? or do we need to dispatch new events for that purpose?

Comment: If you refer here to 'time travel' it may be possible, but you will likely have to perform Compensating Transaction, because a monetary refund will be subject to a different event flow than the initial money transfer. But ideally the failure should be handled in your design's eventual consistency of a transaction where a PaymentReceived isn't available on such events. So the process flows can't continue and you might retry the failed actions / commands.